# Can I apply for a US visit visa from Singapore while my immigration visa form i-130 is still pending?

Tags: visas

I am a Singaporean married to my husband who is from hongkong. He is a US PR working in US now. We have submitted our visa application in July 2017 under form i-130.

Currently i visit him via visa waiver once a year staying for 2 weeks.

May i know how long can i wait to return to US if i use visa waiver to stay till the maximum 90days?